# How to unset session variables from a webhook?

Tags: php

I'm using Stripe for PHP to take payments. The booking process all happens on `/booking/index.php`. When they are ready to pay, they click a button that redirects them to the stripe checkout via js. On successful payment, a webhook is sent to `/webhooks/success.php`, then they are redirected to `/confirmed/index.php`. I would like to unset them in the `/confirmed`, but the problem is if the user never makes it to `/confirmed`, the variables won't get unset. How would I go about unsetting these variables from my `/success` webhook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the user's session ID in the metadata of the Stripe purchase request. This metadata will be included in data sent to the webhook. The webhook can then use that session ID to update session variables.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$event = json_decode($json, true);
$session_id = $event['data']['object']['metadata']['session_id'];
session_start();
session_id($session_id);
unset($_SESSION['somevar']);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was wanting to do! I just didn't know if it would work. Thank you!